# ICS Invite is not getting added to calendar automatically on invite

Tags: icalendar

Below is the ICS file format :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST; name=invite.ics'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:GMT
BEGIN:STANDARD
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=rkarvir@digite.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:rkarvir@digite.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=rkarvir@digite.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:rkarvir@digite.com
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=rkarvir@digite.com;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:rkarvir@digite.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20231023T060000
DESCRIPTION:Outlook Invite Test using SENDOUTLOOKCALENDARICSINVITE
DTEND;TZID=GMT:20231023T110000
DTSTAMP:20231023T060000
DTSTART;TZID=GMT:20231023T060000
LAST-MODIFIED:20231023T060000
ORGANIZER;CN=no-reply@digite.com:mailto:no-reply@digite.com
SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Outlook invite test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:24185396639688100648742110050169689808572026479082155165655176806312270322825734562502581671195530307722709231344647
1

X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Tried adding the header as mentioned :

```
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST; name=invite.ics'
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=invite.ics
```

Also added the below property :

```
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED
```